# Effects of having too much vitamin D?

Tags: human-biology, vitamins

I saw there was another question about vitamin D; however, I do not believe this is a repeat.
What are some of the effects/side effects of having too much vitamin D in your body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a rare condition that can only occur when taking too much doses of vitamin D. It has nothing to do with sun exposure.

High levels of vitamin D stimulate hypercalcemia and all its [negative consequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercalcaemia#Signs_and_symptoms). It can also exacerbate liver and kidney chronic diseases.

Reference: Katherine Zeratsky, [*What is vitamin D toxicity, and should I worry about it since I take supplements?*](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/expert-answers/vitamin-d-toxicity/faq-20058108)